# Azure service fabric create package command line

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-service-fabric, azure-powershell

I've seen is possible to push Azure Service Fabric applications using PowerShell, but for this the package of the application is a pre-requisite, and in all tutorials I can only create it through visual studio.
Is there any way to create the package from command-line?
I plan to create my package on the build server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic answer for command line is this:

```
msbuild Application.sfproj /t:Package /p:Configuration=[Debug|Release]
```

The article on setting up continuous integration that Raphael posted goes into more detail about how to set this up in a VSTS build definition.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have a good guide here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-set-up-continuous-integration/#create-your-build-definition