# How to publish azure service fabric project from command line (powershell, cmd, etc.)

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric, ms-publisher

**What I have:**

Several separate repositories with .NET solutions.
Each solution has a `Service Fabric Project (.sfproj)`.
Each `sfproj` has a needed publish profile.
Local Service Fabric cluster, which is used for development/debugging.

**What I need:**

I want to create a `ps` script which will go solution by solution and deploy the projects to the local service fabric cluster. Right now I'm opening each solution in VS and I'm publishing the app from VS. And it takes a lot of time.

**Main question:**

How to write a command that will build and publish the `sfproj` using needed `publish profile`?

*P.S.: I have read [Azure service fabric create package command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38077846/3016769) question here. But I don't understand how to include the needed publish profile.*